# How could I make my Python 3 code more compact?

Tags: python, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

This is my code and I find it to be a bit bulky and repetitive.
    """
    Key
    UCIO = User Chosen Input Operation
    x = Global variable, The first number the user would operate with
    y = Global variable, The second number the user would operate with
    z = Local variable, The resulting number of the chosen operation
    """

```
# Declaring the types of operates the user cold use
print("Select an operation")
print("1. Addition")
print("2. Subtraction")
print("3. Multiplication")
print("4. Division")
print("5. Power")

# Making the code look neater
print("")

# Gathering information from the user to calculate equation
UCIO = input("Enter an operation 1/2/3/4/5: ")
x = input("Enter your first number: ")
y = input("Enter your second number: ")

# Making the code look neater
print("")

# Calculating an equation with the operation "+"
if UCIO == "1":
    z = float(x) + float(y)
    print(x + " " + "+" + " " + y + " " + "=" + " " + str(z))

# Calculating an equation with the operation "-"
elif UCIO == "2":
    z = float(x) - float(y)
    print(x + " " + "-" + " " + y + " " + "=" + " " + str(z))

# Calculating an equation with the operation "*"
elif UCIO == "3":
    z = float(x) * float(y)
    print(x + " " + "*" + " " + y + " " + "=" + " " + str(z))

# Calculating an equation with the operation "/"
elif UCIO == "4":
    z = float(x) / float(y)
    print(x + " " + "/" + " " + y + " " + "=" + " " + str(z))

# Calculating an equation with the operation "^"
elif UCIO == "5":
    z = float(x) ** float(y)
    print(x + " " + "^" + " " + y + " " + "=" + " " + str(z))
```

Comment: Hint: use the value of `UCIO` to set a string variable `op_str` and a function `op`, then use `op_str` and `op` to define `z` and print the result *once*.

Comment: Have you checked out `click`? Awesome also does a good job creating lists of frameworks. You can pick a CLI framework that you like: https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#command-line-tools

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments, you can use the value of `UCIO` and link it to the target function to be used.

1. Create a dictionary that contains the `UCIO`. With each `UCIO` having an `alias`, a `message` and an operating function `fct`
2. Print all the possible options by iterating through the dictionary and selecting its `message` key
3. Gather your inputs, `UCIO`, `x` and `y`
4. If `UCIO` is in the possible options, use the corresponding operating function `fct` from the dictionary
5. Else notify an error

---

```
ops = {}
ops['1'] = { 'alias': '+', 'message': 'Addition', 'fct': lambda x, y : x + y }
ops['2'] = { 'alias': '-', 'message': 'Substraction', 'fct': lambda x, y : x - y }
ops['3'] = { 'alias': '*', 'message': 'Multiplication', 'fct': lambda x, y : x * y }
ops['4'] = { 'alias': '/', 'message': 'Division', 'fct': lambda x, y : x / y }
ops['5'] = { 'alias': '^', 'message': 'Power', 'fct': lambda x, y : x ** y }

for k in ops.keys():
    print(f'{k}. {ops[k]["message"]}')

UCIO = input(f"Enter an operation {'/'.join(ops.keys())} : ")
x = input("Enter your first number: ")
y = input("Enter your second number: ")

if UCIO in ops and UCIO in ops:
    result = ops[UCIO]['fct'](float(x), float(y))
    print(f'{x} {ops[UCIO]["alias"]} {y} = {result}')
else:
    print('No candidates for the operation {UCIO}')
```